# Excel KPI on a calculated measure from SSAS

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

We have an SSAS multidimensional OLAP cube with a number of measures and KPI's.

End users connect to this via excel.

In a few cases users have created calculated measures in excel, which included in the pivot table.

They want to add KPI indicators on this calculated measure that look the same as the kpi indicators they get from OLAP. Is this possible?

Note: This is not using power pivot or dax.